# Reuse existing AngularJS service in VueJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, service

Is there a way to reuse existing AngularJS services in a VueJS project? I mean reuse not migrate! I've read a lot of posts where migration from AngularJS to VueJS was discussed.

Background: We are setting up a new Electron app, but would like to reuse existing AngularJS services from an older AngularJS project which still uses these services and which are still being maintained. I'd like to link to those files and thus having those services (and latest fixes) available in the new app. In order to move away from legacy AngularJS my first thought was of course to go with Angular because it offers the so called UpgradeModule. I know there are different opinions, but to me Angular is over-engineered by far, builds are very slow which is especially cumbersome in dev mode (can't use live reloading, because of a CORS issue with ng serve and the real server on the web) and adds a lot of unnecessary complexity and restraints as well. This is the reason why I'd like to try VueJS.

Comment: by re-using you mean add angularjs let say service.js file in vue project?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A .js file containing something like this: app.service ( 'myService', function() { ... } )

Comment: I dont think so that is possible because both frameworks handle dependencies differently. However what you can do is write the service in Simple javascript and have it included on both projects.